# Radius Determination for 2D data cloud

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry

I have a 2D dataset and converted it to a point cloud using cv2.threshold. For this point cloud I want to determine the radius of the central circle. The approach with Hough Circles does not seem to work.

An example file from my dataset is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36X7b.jpg) and my code for determining the point cloud is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys


image = cv2.imread("600.png")
orig_image = np.copy(image)
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 1)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1,1), 0)


# apply binary thresholding
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 145, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('image', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('image_thres1.png', thresh)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)                                      
image_copy = image.copy()

cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('None approximation', image_copy)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('contours_none_image1.png', image_copy)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For example my point cloud looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3b3x.png).

I then tried to estimate the radius by specifying what percentage of the data points should be in a circle, but this is not useful as small percentage changes change the radius extremely.

I can see the central circle without problems with my eye, but I can't find a way to determine the radius or just an enclosing circle.

Is there an elegant solution or algorithm for my problem?

Comment: IMO, you forget to tell us that this is the DFT of an image, and that cloud is centered. Also, the border of the cloud is fuzzy and there is no exact radius to be found. You probably have the info to specify an ROI only containing this cloud. Then binarizing the blurred image should give you a single blob of which finding the radius from the area is easy. Forget Hough, it is not appropriate here.

Comment: It is true, it is a DFT of an image. What is an ROI? I have no information regarding the radius of the fuzzy point cloud at the center.

Comment: Region of Interest

Comment: ok thanks. But I have no information regarding the radius of the fuzzy point cloud at the center and i don't know how i could get a single blob.

Answer (score 0):

After Gauss lowpass and binarization:

[image]

Note that your circle is not really a circle.

Comment: ok i managed to get the gaussian lowpass and the binarization. How can I estimate the radius now?

Comment: I said that: from area.